# Solving bivariate normal distribution for the correlation coefficient given values of parameters

Tags: statistics

If I was given the parameters of a bivariate normal distribution (X,Y) and the probability
$$\mathbb{P}[a<X<b|Y=y] = k$$
How do I find the correlation coefficient $\rho$?

What I tried to do is $$f(x|Y=y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
$$\int_a^bf(x|Y=y) = k$$
I then try to solve for the integral and then just solve for $\rho$. However, when I try to do this, it just leads to a function that is difficult to integrate and uses the error function. Am I missing something? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know or can you find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$?

Comment: No, sorry, just the means and variances of X and Y, so there's an unknown $\rho$ in the distribution of  X given Y